# Crash in core data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

Can anyone help me to understand what does this crash log mean?

```
0 CoreFoundation 0x314df29e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x3918497a objc_exception_throw + 26
2 CoreFoundation 0x314e2e02 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 166
3 CoreFoundation 0x314e152c ___forwarding___ + 388
4 CoreFoundation 0x31438f64 __forwarding_prep_0___ + 20
5 CoreData 0x3128b9f8 -[NSSQLCore _prepareResultsFromResultSet:usingFetchPlan:withMatchingRows:] + 3004
6 CoreData 0x31288fa2 -[NSSQLCore _newRowsForFetchPlan:selectedBy:withArgument:] + 1274
7 CoreData 0x31282084 -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 308
8 CoreData 0x3128173a -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 678
9 CoreData 0x31281200 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 464
10 CoreData 0x31280618 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 1640
11 CoreData 0x3127ef12 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] +
```

Edit : This crash occurs rarely.Unable to re-produce with break points.

Comment: Why you think its a core data problem?

Comment: Do you know the fetch request that was executed, the exception message (what is the selector)?

Comment: I you haven't yet, then turn on Exception Breakpoint(s). It will help you trace the root cause.

Comment: @Damir179 : this occurs rarely.

Comment: @Karthik207 Add exception breakpoints both for onThrow and onCatch.. then run your code..

Comment: @OlegSobolev : stack trace shows that its a core data issue right?.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say line 2 is the best indicator:

2 CoreFoundation 0x314e2e02 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 166

It looks like the call in line 5 to _prepareResultsFromResultSet:usingFetchPlan:withMatchingRows: is being sent somewhere it shouldn't be.